# Is this the correct way to calculate geostrophic wind velocity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Formula I found online:

$$V_{GWS} = \frac{1}{2\Omega\sin(lat)} \cdot \frac{1}{\rho} \cdot \frac{\Delta p}{d}$$

Here is my problem:
[image]

My solution:
$$V_{GWS} = \frac{1}{14.6\cdot10^{-5}\cdot(-0.43)} \cdot \frac{1}{0.70} \cdot \frac{800}{400000} \frac{\text{Pa}}{\text{m}}= -4.55$$

Wind speed shouldn't be negative, right? So something seems off. Would greatly appreciate the help. Am confused at what direction the wind would be moving too.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(35\,\text{rad})=-0.4282$ but $\sin(35°)=0.5736$. Everything else is OK. Put your calculator in degrees mode!

Oh yes, wind flows counterclockwise around a low pressure center in the northern hemisphere so along an isobar to the northeast.

Comment: So that would mean that the wind flows parallel to the isobars right? So the direction would be down and to the right?

Comment: No. down and to the right would be in the direction of the pressure gradient, at orthogonal trajectories to the isobars. The wind flows to the northeast, up and to the right following that isobar from Midland, TX to Woodward, OK.